# how to convert a functions Hook in to class state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a todo app both in functional components and class-based components ;

in Functions

```
function addTodo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!text.length) {
      return alert("Plese Write a todo");
    }
    const newItem = {
      text: text,
      id: Date.now(),
    }
    setItems(prevList => [...prevList, newItem])
    console.log(newItem);

    setText("");

    inputRef.current.focus();


  }
```

but in class When I am Setting the state of items it gives me an error

```
    addTodo(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.text.length) {
            return alert("Plese Write a todo");
        }

        const newItem = {
            text: this.state.text,
            id: Date.now()
        }

        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items((prevList) => [...prevList, newItem]),
            text: "",
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post all of your code including imports so we can see everything that's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `this.state.items((prevList) => [...prevList, newItem])` is wrong.

Can you try changing it to `[...this.state.items, newItem]` because `this.state.items` does not have a function?

Comment: This answer does not take into account that `setState` is asynchronous, so `this.state` may not have the current values you expect.  It is recommended to use the callback parameter of `setState` as mentioned in my answer to ensure values are current.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

In class-based component in react, you need to bind the function to class inside class constructor to use this keyword.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this); // add this line
}
```

Now you can use this.setState inside addTodo function.
There is one more way where you need not bind this.
You can use the arrow function instead of a normal one.

```
   addTodo = (event) => {    //just modify this line
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.text.length) {
            return alert("Plese Write a todo");
        }

        const newItem = {
            text: this.state.text,
            id: Date.now()
        }

        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items((prevList) => [...prevList, newItem]),
            text: "",
        });
    }
```

You can read more about difference between regular function and arrow function here- https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that `this.state.items` is an array, not a function taking a callback.

```
this.setState({
  items: this.state.items((prevList) => [...prevList, newItem]),
  text: "",
});
```

When using the setter from `useState`, you get the current state as a callback parameter, as shown in `setItems(prevList => [...prevList, newItem])`.

In a class based `setState`, you get the callback parameter there, *not* where you're accessing the item.

For your code, you want:

```
this.setState(state => (
  items: [...state.items, newItem],
  text: "",
));
```